# why the process of introspecting schema XXX(completely) run for minutes when I use DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

On DataGrip 2019.3.5 , connect to mysql 5.3. There is always a process of introspecting schema XXX(completely) run for many minutes. About 10 minutes. How to speed up or closs the process

Comment: Hello! I am Max from DataGrip team. This doesn't look ok :) Please send us logs to datagrip@jetbrains.com.
Help | Show logs in...
and
Help | Show SQL logs in...

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL 5.3 was used 2011-2013. Don't you think it's time to update?